# Is there an estimation of the number of zero-days out there?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, zero-day, vulnerability-markets

> A zero day vulnerability refers to a hole in software that is unknown
> to the vendor.

Since, zero day vulnerabilities are unknown can any estimation of amounts be made? What are possible scenarios to estimate the amount of zero-days? *For example, based on experience with buying/selling zero day vulnerabilities.*

I wonder how many undiscovered bugs there approximately are in the world and how many known zero day vulnerabilities with exploits there are approximately.

Comment: Do you mean zero days that someone has a working exploit for? Or undiscovered bugs in total.

Comment: @paj28 both would be interesting numbers, I'll change the question.

Comment: For organizations such as the NSA, CIA, Mossad, PRC, a zero-day exploit has great value and is usually kept secret for their own personal use. These organizations have people whose sole job is to discover these for the organization's use. With that said, I am going to say any numbered published about 0days is not going to be reliable.

Comment: @ncd275 Unreliable? More like flat out wrong. If those exploits are published, they aren't zero day anymore.

Comment: If you are talking about unknown ones and are including any deployment of bad code on any number of poorly written websites or applications I would say Millions easily.  If you are talking about ones only known to a few people or organizations there is truly no way to accurately know because we can't determine levels of effort spent finding them but there would be a huge gap between these two amounts.

Comment: I think you may want to narrow your scope a bit.  Zero days in what software?  Zero days with what effect?  Does a zero day in a companies internal tools count, or do you mean only commercial software?  If commercial software, hold old and for what?  For instance, if I found a zero-day in a 1993 copy of Doom, does that count?  What's your distinction between a bug, and a true exploit?  If I can cheat at doom, does that count?  I think the question is interesting, but I think you need to flesh out some scope here, and at least start out with a much narrower one.

Comment: An exploit broker doesn't know how many 0days _exist_. I could tell you how many 0days _I_ have. I could tell you how many 0days I have _heard of_, including mere rumors. I could tell you the _price_ of certain kinds of 0days. But the number itself? I would guess within 4 orders of magnitude of one million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vulnerabilities, in general, exist before they are found by researchers so the number already in existence but not yet known could be very high. As for known Vulnerabilities that would constitute Zero-Days where an exploit exists but are still held privately by a few people or organizations, there is really no way to know because too many of these organizations are very secretive for obvious reasons. It is too hard to speculate how much effort has been put into finding Zero-Days globally much less how productive those people or organizations have been at doing so.

That said the following Rand Corporation paper has a lot of very relevant information to your question.

[Zero Days, Thousands of Nights "The Life and Times of Zero-Day Vulnerabilities and Their Exploits](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_reports/RR1700/RR1751/RAND_RR1751.pdf) 
http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_reports/RR1700/RR1751/RAND_RR1751.pdf

Something to also keep in mind is there has been a lot of advances in fuzzing technology in the last few years which may make finding new zero-days easier for attackers.

Answer (score 0):

We can approximate the number of unknown bugs from the number of known bugs. There aren't many reliable numbers on that, because vendors have different disclosure policies, so even the numbers we have are hard to compare. But when we're talking about security-relevant bugs, not just, say, cosmetics or usability, we can look at **disclosed vulnerabilities** and get an image, such as:

https://www.cvedetails.com/

(ignore the CVSS scores, CVSS is nonsense)

we also see the numbers over time: https://www.cvedetails.com/browse-by-date.php

and by vendor: https://www.cvedetails.com/top-50-vendors.php

We note that the number of vulnerabilities is going up over time, not down. Even looking at individual vendors over time, this is largely true. The question of whether this is because software is getting worse, there simply is more and more complex software, or people are more aggressively discovering and publishing bugs is for another day.

To estimate how many bugs are **currently** discovered but not publicly known, we would have to guess at the time between the first discovery by someone and the making public. That's pretty much impossible and it varies widely. We know about some high-profile vulnerabilities that they were known in certain circles for many months and sometimes several years. Other vulnerabilities have no known exploitations before they became public, so if someone knew about them before they played it very close to the chest. So all we can do is rough estimates.

Given this data, I believe it is safe to say that at any given moment, there is somewhere on the order of magnitude of 1,000 zero-days out there. Maybe this week it's only a few hundred, maybe in a bad month last year it was a few thousand, but somewhere in this order of magnitude. Breaking that down to the top vendors, it is probably safe to say that for any of the major players (like Microsoft, Apple, Google, IBM, Cisco, etc.) at any given time there are most likely one or several zero-days out there.

So in summary: No matter what, there is someone out there right now who could break into your systems if they really wanted to.

Comment: _order of magnitude of 1,000 zero-days_ – Huh? It's far, far greater than that. And we really cannot possibly estimate the number based only on published vulnerabilities for countless reasons. How many vulnerabilities do you think have been published for ReactOS? Probably close to 0, but it almost certainly has more 0days than, say, VxWorks which has a _lot_ of published vulns. A thousand for MS products alone is likely an underestimation.

Comment: @forest like I said, a rough estimate based on the available data. Anything beyond that would be speculation. You can certainly speculate, but if you can't back it up with data then it's just throwing something out there.

Comment: @forest also, that is my estimate for the number RIGHT NOW. When some of them get published tomorrow, they aren't zero-days anymore. If you think of the 12k or so from 2019 as a rolling number, you'll come to such figures.

(also also: fun fact: ReactOS has 1 CVE - https://www.cvedetails.com/product/10706/Reactos-Reactos.html?vendor_id=6330)

Comment: That's still a very low estimate. And your method for estimating it still isn't correct. You simply can't judge the number of unpatched vulnerabilities by the number of patched vulnerabilities. Case in point: A few years ago there was a talk at some security con comparing Linux, OpenBSD, FreeBSD, and NetBSD kernels. It showed that, despite Linux having far more CVEs, the code was a lot higher quality than any of the others and has less room for bugs. The developer's handling of security bugs and disclosure culture have more of an impact than the raw number of published bugs.

Comment: Also strictly speaking, a 0day does not need to be known by anyone to still be a 0day. The number of security bugs in Linux pre-2.4 that will never be discovered simply because no one cares about that anymore and natural code churn got rid of the vulnerable code before issues were found out is vast.

Comment: @forest I agree with code quality and sure, many bugs will never be found. But the OP asked for an estimate of zero-days out there and I'm giving him one based on known numbers rather than idle speculation. If you have better data, please feel free to write up an answer with your data.

Comment: My point is that there _is_ no better data. Not even for people in the vuln market, or for exploit brokers or developers. Much research has been done into this and solving it is still an open problem. Sometimes a guess is actually less informative than simply saying "no one knows". That is why I take issue with your claim that we can approximate the number of 0days out there, when no one has been able to do so yet.

Comment: @forest I agree that it is a very rough estimate, that's why I answer in orders of magnitude. I would be surprised if by some magic the actual number became known and it would be 100,000 or it would be 10. "no one knows" is technically correct if you think in precise numbers, just like nobody knows the exact number of humans on the planet or of stars in the galaxy - but we can make estimates, understanding that they are just that.